# Wordpress Catch All URL

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a wordpress page to "run" another page based on the url.  So if I have a main page like:

```
/extensions
```

That will run the regular extensions page.  But if I have urls like:

```
/extensions/test
/extensions/test/again
/extensions/text/again/etc
```

They will all just run the extension (no "s") page:

/extension

The extension page will parse the url and do it's thing at that point.  I tried setting up a redirect rule in the `.htaccess` file like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/extensions/.*
RewriteRule . /extension [L]
```

But I can't seem to get it going.  I'm assuming wordpress is always parsing via the `index.php` file, which is some how trumping my little rewrite possibly.  Is there anyway to set this up on wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33250/multiple-endpoints-to-same-page).

Note that this should go into the `functions.php` file and you will have to hit save in the permalinks settings EVERY time you make a change to the function to see the effects.